# Dynamic Javascript variables innerhtml

Tags: javascript, variables

So I want to somehow add the i to the response + 1 and dont know how.

```
for (var i = 0; i < childs; i++) {
      document.getElementById('age_error' + (i + 1) + '').innerHTML = response.age_error + i + 1 ( it gives me error) ;
    }
```

Comment: Can you specify the error?

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Comment: What are the contents of `response.age_error`?

Comment: response from php ajax that contains like you have to give the age or the age is too high

Comment: Can you `console.log()` the`response.age_error` and tell us what it contains?

Comment: <span id="age_error1" class="text-danger">NaN</span>

Comment: Did not mean that: try writing `console.log(response)` and show us the output in the console in devtools.

Comment: As I mentioned before it should give a response from php ajax.
If I write manually the number it gives the following response:
'A gyermek életkorának megadása kötelező!' It means U have to give the child age.
But if i try to add the number from the index it gives me NaN.
console.log(response.gyermekkor_error1);
( It gives me back what it should)
console.log(response.gyermekkor_error + i + 1);
It gives me back NaN

Comment: Try this: `JSON.stringify( response.age_error )`

Comment: It gives me 'null'.

Comment: seems the response from PHP is not correct.

Comment: What do you mean? getElementById('age_error' + (i + 1) + '') In this case it works,and if i add manually it works too..

Comment: The problem is caused by `response` not by `getElementById`.

Comment: And why is it working when i set it manually? what is the difference between age_error1 or age_error + i + 1 It is literally the same thing.

Comment: in your loop, maybe `childs` should be `childs.length` or if it's an HTML element collection, use `[...childs].length`

Comment: still dont work

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.